# Angular 11 Testing component rendered outside router outlet

Tags: angular, jasmine

Below is a typical code which displays error message common to all component

```
<div>
   <div>
     <app-alert></app-alert>
   </div>
   <div>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </div>
</div>
```

When there is component has an error, the message is going to display inside the `<app-alert>` tag

But the component rendered using `TestBed` will not render that tag

The `<app-alert>` tag is served using `AlertComponent` class and `AlertService` class

The `AlertService` is injected as private via constructor

```
@Component({ templateUrl: 'login.component.html' })
export class LoginComponent {
    constructor(private alertService: AlertService) { }
}
```

In reference to [Angular Testing Basics](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-basics) `fixture.debugElement` will not give the `<app-alert>` tag the reason being the tag is outside the `router-outlet`

How will I test login failure and display of message `invalid credentials` within `login.component.spec.ts`

Comment: That's not a unit but an integration test. Your component should test if the `alertService.showAlert()` is being called with the proper input and that's it; it shouldn't test more than that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a TestHost component that houses both of them in in your `.spec.ts` file.

```
@Component({
  template: `
     <app-alert></app-alert>
     <login></login>
  `
})
class TestHostComponent {
}
.....
TestBed.configureTestingModule({ 
      declarations: [AppAlertComponent, LoginComponent, TestHostComponent],
      providers: [/* your providers */] 
})

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
testHost = fixture.componentInstance;
// get a handle on the login component/class
loginComponent = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(LoginComponent)).componentInstance;
// get a handle on the app alert component/class
alertComponent = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(AppAlertComponent)).componentInstance;
```

With that setup both `login` and `app-alert` will be painted and you can test how they work together.

I think I explained a bit more than this [link](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-inside-a-test-host) but it should help as well.

Comment: thanks, in fact I tried, but I did not know the syntax `fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(LoginComponent))` this is working

Comment: But, the innerText or innerHTML is still empty, how do I trap it before next test component erases it

Comment: I am not sure in how to do that. Is the alert component empty or the login component? Maybe there is an `*ngIf` blocking the view from being rendered?